# The bigger the tree, the further the fruit falls

Tags: quotes, proverbs, literary-english

I overheard this once, but can't seem to find the origin of this quote. I checked Bartlet, Times, Yale, and Oxford, so I'm positive I heard it wrong. It might have been "the taller the tree." I am familiar with "the taller the tree, the deeper the roots," but in this context it was referred to as falling deeper into sin: The more potential a person has for greatness also makes one susceptible to fall even further.
No idea where they got this from.

Comment: "The bigger they are, the harder they fall" is a common idiom in the US.  Usually the implied image is of a person falling, generally in a figurative sense.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a variation of an old German idea. The old nostrum is that **The *apple* does not fall *far* from the tree.** Meaning that a child usually has a similar character or similar qualities to his or her parents:

It was Richard Jente (1888-1952) who said it, or spoke of it in 1933 as an *already old* idea. [yahoo.com]

Sigmund Freud added the important detail of the falling apple; "Nor from the horse."